# I want to use a timer to count the solve time using thread

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

Basically, I'm making a picture puzzle game in java. And I want to use a timer to count the solve time using thread. TIA.[My Current Progress:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBTem.png)

Comment: Instead of posting a link to (an image of) your code, edit your question to include your code. Format it by having a blank line between your question and indent it with four spaces. Also describe what the problem is you would like to have people help you on.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to track the difference in time, you don't need another thread. All you need to do is keep track of a start time, and then you can compute the time elapsed from that start time at any point.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Do stuff...
long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

This will give you the elapsed time in milliseconds, which you can convert to any other form of time that you want.